# Task Scheduler : Console app with Log4Net not working

Tags: c#, console-application, log4net, windows-task-scheduler

I am having one console app that having log4net(V-2.0.15) for logs. Configs are given below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
    </connectionStrings>
    <appSettings>
        <!--<add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>-->
    </appSettings>
<log4net>
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="C:\logs1\log.txt" />
        <encoding value="utf-8" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Date" />
        <!--<maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
        <maximumFileSize value="100MB" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />-->
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="All" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
</startup>
```

C# Code is given below :

```
    private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            ///Coding...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("------- Error Message : " + ex.Message + "------- StackTrace : " + ((ex.StackTrace != null) ? ex.StackTrace.ToString() : ""));
        }
    }
```

Now I publish that console app to local folder and while creating 'Task Scheduler -> Basic Task' I pick exe file and created it. But it is not doing anything. What am I missing here???

Comment: Change `<conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n" />` to `<conversionPattern value="%-5p|%d{ dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss}|%m|%method|%stacktrace{5} (line %line)%newline" />`

Comment: @PauloGuimarães not working

Comment: So probably your `Log` is null. Use `LogManager.GetLogger("RollingLogFileAppender");`

Comment: though not working

Answer (score 0):

log4net.config

```xml
<log4net>
  <root>
    <level value="All" />
    <appender-ref ref="YourLog" />
  </root>

  <appender name="YourLog" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="logs/yourlog.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="3" />
    <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p|%d{ dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss}|%m|%method|%stacktrace{5} (line %line)%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

AssemblyInfo.cs

```cs
// some other stuffs
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config")]
```

code

```cs
    private static readonly ILog _log= LogManager.GetLogger("YourLog");

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {

      try
      {

      }

      catch (Exception e)
      {
         _log.Error("Oh no! Something bad happened", e);
      }
     }
```

The name of the `appender` and the `.config` it does not matter. Only for best practices I would use log4net, since later you would need another config. `App.config` after build will be `YOUR-PROJECT-NAME.config`, this is more for projects configuration.

Comment: In my solution, app.config having that log4net config. what is log4net.config? and where it is located??

Comment: this is how Log4net will read your config. It should be in your project.

Comment: After publishing, I am having this much files in publish folder. Not getting which to update - EPPlus.dll.deploy
- EPPlus.Interfaces.dll.deploy
- EPPlus.System.Drawing.dll.deploy
- log4net.dll.deploy
- Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream.dll.deploy
- TaskScheduler -- Applocation Manifest
- TaskScheduler.exe.config.deploy
- TaskScheduler.exe.deploy
- TaskScheduler.exe.manifest

Comment: Can you please provide me any link? to which I can follow steps and check in my solution?

Comment: Ahh ok, i didnt know you lack in this. I will improve my answer.